# Query Run time with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I tried running a query with an inner join in Sequel Pro to get the most recent records/invoices using this:

```
SELECT tt.Hotel_Property, tt.Preferred_Hotel_Status
FROM hotel_detail tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Hotel_Property, MAX(STR_TO_DATE (`Invoice_Date`, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM hotel_detail
    GROUP BY Hotel_Property) groupedtt 
ON tt.Hotel_Property = groupedtt.Hotel_Property 
AND tt.Invoice_Date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

But it's running the query for a long time and I'm not sure if it'll actually execute (cancelled it after waiting 14 mins). I know it's a lot of data to work through but wondered if anyone had suggestions to make it run faster?

*Ideally I want one record for each hotel property giving the most recent invoice date and the status associated with that max invoice

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need an index or two.

Comment: On a sidenote: `Invoice_Date` is a string? Why? And you make it a date (`MaxDateTime`), but compare this date again with the string `Invoice_Date`? This doesn't look good to me.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) and 
 
 [**How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: You should read https://use-the-index-luke.com/ to learn how use the index to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge sequel pro uses MySQL so you might no be able to use analytical functions but try the following:

```
SELECT 
Hotel_Property
, Preferred_Hotel_Status
, MAX(STR_TO_DATE (`Invoice_Date`, '%m/%d/%Y')) OVER(PARTITION BY hotel_property) AS MaxDateTime
FROM hotel_detail
```

If this doesn't work then I'd suggest running the query in 'chunks' based on the date. So maybe run a day at a time by employing a WHERE clause. I.E.:

```
SELECT tt.Hotel_Property, tt.Preferred_Hotel_Status
FROM hotel_detail tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Hotel_Property, MAX(STR_TO_DATE (`Invoice_Date`, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM hotel_detail
WHERE DATE = "the_date_you_want_to_run"
    GROUP BY Hotel_Property) groupedtt 
ON tt.Hotel_Property = groupedtt.Hotel_Property 
AND tt.Invoice_Date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime 
WHERE DATE = "the_date_you_want_to_run"
```

Then you can either look at the results for different days separately, or simply INSERT them into a new table where you can perform more analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a correlated subquery:

```
select hd.*
from hotel_detail hd
where str_to_date(hd.invoice_date, '%m/%d/%Y') =
          (select max(str_to_date(hd2.invoice_date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
           from hotel_detail hd2
           where hd2.hotel_property = hd.hotel_property
          );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `hotel_detail(hotel_property, invoice_date)`.  The index would be more effective if you stored the date properly using the native SQL format of `date` or `datetime`.

Comment: because OP is using `str_to_date` I dont think and index on that field would help. But as you suggest, saving the date as date or datetime would.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . It has a minor help, because the subquery can be satisfied entirely using the index ("the index covers the subquery").  It would be much better if the column were stored correctly.